# What data type to store raw IMAP fetched email messages in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, email, imap

I need to store email messages as soon as they are fetched from IMAP in the database for later processing. I extract the message using a `FETCH` request and data is returned using `BODY.PEEK[]`.

From my understanding, all IMAP messages are returned as `US-ASCII` (the mail servers accept only that), but I could be wrong.

My options (in order of what I think it's right) are:

- US-ASCII text column
- Bytea
- BLOB

I was thinking about using US-ASCII but I'm afraid of having problems with encoding, I don't know if there are "faulty" IMAP servers not returning us-ascii mails. 
The alternative is Bytea, but I read you have to deal with encoding, so I'm not sure what's the advantage/disadvantage over US-ASCII.
BLOB is raw, and I'm not sure about the problems it deliver in this case. I assume I have to deal with the bytes-to-string conversion.

What's the recommended data type?

Comment: What library/language are you using?

Comment: Can you use UTF-8 encoded text?

Comment: Classic email is *supposed* to be US_AScii, but in practise it is not, and can have high byte characters.  The interpretation depends on the headers, so a text type is not appropriate.

Comment: I'm using Ruby as language and downloading messages using `net/imap` with `uid_fetch`. I fetch the whole message with `FetchData#attr["BODY[]"]` and so far that string comes always encoded as us-ascii.
I don't need to perform any operation on that text, it's later on fetched back, parsed and created a "usable" version of it

Comment: @joanolo UTF-8 encoded text from my understanding it's really problematic since a raw message from IMAP comes with bytes that can't be converted straight to utf-8

Comment: @Max I'm referring to the email as a whole, including headers and everything. I'm aware that the body could be in different encoding and has different parts, but when I say _raw_ I mean that I literally need to store the whole thing with headers and everything. I believe that stream of byte is in a specific encoding (us-ascii), am I wrong?

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL Yes.  Standards compliant email is (was) 7-bit US-ASCII.  A large amount of email is not fully standards compliant.  8-bit stuff sneaks into them.  They should be stored as non-textual data.  Also, 8-bit email has been coming for years (see SMTPUTF8 and IMAP UTF8 extensions).  Also, very few mail servers will outright reject a message with 8-bit stuff, even if undeclared.

Comment: @Max ok thanks that's a good point. I'm considering bytea for storage at this point.

Comment: Very much *was* - lots of clients assume 8-bit clean transport at this point. They shouldn't, but they do. But anyway, unless you're going to force the whole DB to US-ASCII, you *have* to use bytea to avoid encoding issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For small objects such as emails, I think you're going to be better off with Bytea. The storage and handling is different and since your objects are going to be small, it seems like it would be handled better as Bytea. See [here](https://www.microolap.com/products/connectivity/postgresdac/help/tipsandtricks_byteavsoid.htm) for a comparison of the two by Microolap. That's not a full answer to your question but might take one option off the list.

Comment: That link is quite helpful with the description "a programmer thinks as raw bytes"!

Comment: Yes, and you should NOT assume email lacks NULL bytes, is correctly encoded, correctly declares encoding, doesn't mix encodings, etc. bytea is the only correct choice here IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You're making the very much unwarranted assumption that you can avoid dealing with encodings.

You can't.

Whether you use lob, bytea, or a `text` column that you assume contains 7-bit mail only... the mail is just arbitrary binary data. You do not know its text encoding. In practice mail clients have used 8-bit encoding forever; either standards-compliant via MIME quoted-printable, or often simply raw 8-bit text.

Some clients have even been known to include full 8-bit MIME segments that include null (zero) bytes. PostgreSQL won't tolerate that in a `text` column.

But even for clients using compliant MIME, quoted-printable escaping text bodies, etc... the mail may contain non-ASCII chars, they're just escaped. Indexing these and ignoring the escapes will yield weird and wrong results. Also, attachments will usually be arbitrary base64 data. Indexing this as text is utterly meaningless. Then there's all the HTML bodies, multi-part/alternative segments, CSS, etc...

When dealing with email, assume that anything a client or server can do wrong, it will do wrong. For storage, treat the email as raw bytes of unknown encoding. That's exactly what `bytea` is for.

If you want to do *anything* with the mail you'll need a defensive MIME parser that can extract the MIME parts, cope with broken parts, etc. It'll need to check the declared encoding (if any) against the actual mime-part body, and guess encodings if none are declared or the declared encoding is obviously wrong. It'll have to deal with all sorts of bogus MIME structure and contents; quoted-printable bodies that aren't really quoted-printable, and all that.

So if you plan to *index* this email, it's definitely not as simple as "create a fulltext index and merrily carry on". The question with that is not *if* it will fail but *when*.

Personally, if I had to do this (and given the choice I wouldn't) I'd store the raw email as bytea. Then for search I'd decompose it into MIME parts, detect text-like parts, do encoding detection and dequoting, etc, and inject the decoded and cleaned up text bodies into a separate table for text indexing.

There are some useful Perl modules for this that you can possibly use via `plperlu`, but I'd likely do it in an outside script/tool instead. Then you have your choice of MIME processors, languages, etc.

Comment: Hey Craig, I think you are misunderstanding, I just need to store the raw message. There is no purpose of indexing or anything, just pure storage. The actual decoding of the message happens at a later point, where I fetch this raw stream of bytes from the database, do some mail-parsing magic with a library and only at this point I have something that is text, with proper encoding. So I'm looking for just storing in the database the most raw version of data, to later act upon it. It seems that bytea is enough based on your answer, thanks

Comment: Yes, bytea is definitely the way to go.